Bare dirt in California. Gonna seed with rye
Okay. The dirt is bare with out weeds. May have some underneath. Can't see. Can I put a weed killer than put the rye seed on top? Weed killer killed the lawn and had to redo it.
Anything else you suggest. What rye is the best and how much to water after seeding?
Do just do rye grass, dirt, compost then watering?

What weed killer are you proposing ?

Yes, no weeds growing is suspicious.

Should I just have straight dirt, seeds then compost?

I'm not an expert on grass, but I think that grass seeds should be very near the surface - so I'd imagine it would be more appropriate to mix the compost and dirt (compost is to strong for most plants by itself), then sprinkle the seeds on top and rake it in, or cover it with a very thin layer (about the height of the seed / 5-7mm )  of topsoil and water in.

I don't think many weed killers will kill roots (when there is no foliage) and seeds.  You just have to keep pulling them out.
There are weed killers called pre-emergent, which are pretty nasty.  I have used them for pines.  They are not cheap and require protection to apply. These will stop weeds from emerging, but they are pretty targeted - they kill everything except some species.

Pre-emergents will prevent the grass seed from germinating...
